# ASP.Net Impersonate specific User temporarily, then revert back to previous Impersonated User

Tags: asp.net, impersonation

In my current ASP.Net site, I am already using impersonation to run all of the requests under:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Then, I want to grab the status of a service. this creates a double hop, so I impersonate a specific user.  I am then able to query the service on the remote machine.

I then want to undo the specific impersonation and revert back to the users original impersonation.

When I try the examples linked below, it always reverts back to the ASP.Net user.

[How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/impersonation-in-net)
[Help Understanding Impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395422/help-understanding-impersonation)

My page/controller needs to follow the following example:

1) Request made as BoFlexson  --Auto impersonates as BoFlexson

2) Impersonate ServiceUser: Ask for Service Status

3) Revert Back to BoFlexson:  Do some other task.

4) Impersonate ServiceUser: Ask for Service Status Again

5) Revert Back to BoFlexson:  Do some other task.

Again, when I try to Undo the impersonation context, it goes all the way back to the ASP.Net user, as if I didn't have the     <identity impersonate="true" /> setting at all.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered re-impersonating BoFlexson when you disable impersonation for ServiceUser?

Comment: I have tried saving off the CurrentUser, then doing impersonate again, but this seems to fail:

    CurentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

    .....

    CurrentUser.Impersonate()