# Checking Service Status on a remote computer

Tags: vb.net

I am hopping this will be an easy question. I am trying to use `ServiceProcess`to check and see if a service is running on a remote computer. My issue is, I need to enter credentials (Domain/Username and Password).

So In the below code, how would I incorporate that?

```
Dim services() As ServiceController = ServiceController.GetServices("remote pc name")
```

Comment: ServiceController uses the credentials of the current user, so you will probably have to use WMI instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335065/check-status-of-services-that-run-in-a-remote-computer-using-c-sharp