# Check and change windows service status by C# WebApplication

Tags: c#, networking, server, windows-services, servicecontroller

I need to check and change the status of the webservices on the server by webapplication. I have searched and tried many solutions like [thisone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335065/check-status-of-services-that-run-in-a-remote-computer-using-c-sharp). but no success. I can perform the codes of changing service status on local machine with starting my visual studio with administrator. but the same code is not working when i upload my web application on server.

Any help would be appritiable.

I know `ServiceController` and i have used it. Please guide.

Comment: Most likely a matter of permission?

Comment: yes may be that is thing i need to have